# Auto login in raspi-config not available (Xenial 16.04)

Tags: raspberry-pi3, autologin

I am currently programming a robot that is controlled by a raspberry-pi3 b with Xenial 16.04.

When i turn it on, the raspberry needs to automatically start up and launch some python programs. The problem is that it gets stuck on the login screen, waiting for me to press 'ok' (i removed the password).

Auto login isn't available in raspi-config, and going into System > Users and groups doesn't offer the option either.

I've tried using systemd service and other solutions but none have worked for now. Do you have any ideas how i could login automatically into my session?

Answer (score 0):

Auto login IS available in raspi-config.

1. Run `sudo raspi-config`;
2. Scroll down to `Boot Options` and press `Enter`;
3. Select `Desktop/CLI`;
4. You should see the options for `Desktop Autologin` or `Console Autologin`.

This is based on Raspbian Stretch.

You should not mess with systemd service.